# root-доступ через sftp

Tags: linux

Каким образом можно дать root доступ filezill'e через sftp?

Comment: А может лучше не надо?

Comment: Звучит подозрительно. А расскажите пожалуйста, какую задачу вы хотите решить таким образом?

Comment: http://filezilla.ru/documentation/Howto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй это, но это может навредить

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config 
Last line : AllowUsers root
service sshd restart
```

Используйте аккуратно

Answer (score 1):

Я добовляю авторизацию по ключам. Парольная авторизация для рута отключена поумолчанию.